# Is there a way to hide a macro pattern from docs?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

As of Rust 1.6.0, the generated documentation hides the implementation of each macro pattern:

[image: macro implementation hidden]

Is there a way to hide some of the patterns from the Cargo-generated docs?

```
macro_rules! mc {
    // hide this entire pattern
    (@impl, $arg:expr) => { 42 + $arg };
    // but not this one
    ($arg:expr) => { mc!(@impl, $arg) };
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this is the optimum solution:

```
/// Not meant to be called directly
#[doc(hidden)]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! hidden {
    ( $hidden_rule1:expr ) => { ... };
    ( $hidden_rule2:expr ) => { ... };
    ...
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! public {
    ( $public:expr ) => ( hidden!($public) );
}
```

This uses a separate `hidden` macro (which will probably need to be public) but which is not part of the documentation. All the rules that should be hidden will be hidden and the public one will be visible in the `public` macro which is part of the documentation.

Comment: Note that if a user explicitly imports the macro (`#[macro_use(public)] extern crate ...`) they'll receive an error and also need to include `hidden`: `#[macro_use(public, hidden)] extern crate...`.

Comment: I wrote an attribute macro to handle this automatically: https://crates.io/crates/clean-macro-docs

Answer (score 2):

One option is to have a dummy macro with only the public arms, and use attributes to choose which one rustdoc sees:

````rust
/// Do a thing
///
/// ```
/// # extern crate my_crate;
/// # use my_crate::mc;
/// assert_eq!(mc!(58), 100);
/// ```
#[cfg(doc)]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mc {
    ($arg:expr) => { ... };
}

#[cfg(not(doc))]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! mc {
    (@impl, $arg:expr) => { 42 + $arg };
    ($arg:expr) => { mc!(@impl, $arg) };
}
````

Note: this will only work if you don't use the macro internally.