# What's the significance of __impl in a macro pattern?

Tags: macros, rust

In the following example, taken from `nom`, the string `__impl` appears in the first pattern. What is this element in terms of formal syntax and why is it there?

I'm under the impression that the literal `__impl` in the pattern and the subsequent invocations are used as a dummy-string during pattern-matching, to separate the internally used patterns from the public ones. However, the "internal" match arm is hidden from `rustdoc` as well. Does the `__impl`-part have any more significance to Rust?

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! map(
  // Internal parser, do not use directly
  (__impl $i:expr, $submac:ident!( $($args:tt)* ), $g:expr) => (
    ...
  );
  ($i:expr, $submac:ident!( $($args:tt)* ), $g:expr) => (
    map!(__impl $i, $submac!($($args)*), $g);
  );
  ($i:expr, $f:expr, $g:expr) => (
    map!(__impl $i, call!($f), $g);
  );
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that the literal `__impl` in the pattern and the subsequent invocations are used as a dummy-string during pattern-matching, to separate the internally used patterns from the public ones.

That is correct. It's an internal implementation detail that users should not know of or use. However, macros have to be public because they are ultimately expanded "by the user" at the usage site.

> However, the "internal" match arm is hidden from `rustdoc` as well.

I don't know what you mean, that arm [is in the documentation](https://docs.rs/nom/4.0.0/nom/macro.map.html):

[image: __impl in docs]

See also:

- [Is there a way to hide a Rust macro pattern from docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35537758/155423)

> Does the `__impl`-part have any more significance to Rust?

No. Many times you'll see this pattern prepended with another unlikely-to-occur sigil like `@` or `~`.

Comment: So, does `rustdoc` know about "__impl" to special-case it?